# Create an order using transactions API

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm trying to create a simple order using transactions API on actions on Google, for this, I'm using [this](https://github.com/actions-on-google/apiai-transactions-nodejs) sample app, but when I try to place the order, the device times out, instead of showing the receipt details. The weird thing is that [this](https://github.com/actions-on-google/apiai-transactions-nodejs/blob/master/functions/index.js#L154-L160) code gets executed (I added some logs locally to make sure).

Has anyone been able to run this sample app successfully? I already enabled the actions on Google API on my project on Google cloud, so I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1):

First, you got to make sure you have enabled transaction support for your app.

[image]

If you are testing on the simulator, disable Sandbox mode (checkbox on top right).

> Sandbox ensures that any transactions or orders made during simulation are fake

Comment: Hey Thanks for the answer, but I already have that option enabled and sandbox mode disabled. Were you able to make the transaction sample to show you receipt details after order placement?

Comment: The order receipt is created now, not sure why, but I think it is safe to consider your response as valid hehe, thanks!

Comment: thanks for the confirmation. can you please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this issue before.
You have to keep in mind that the Order ID gets tracked so it needs to be different every time you run the app. That is why I decided to use a UUID time stamp function to make sure the Order ID will be different every time.

I'm referring to wherever it mentions 'UNIQUE_ORDER_ID' in the code. Once you take care of this issue, you will see the receipt every time you run the demo.